# What's the formula for border growth?

Tags: civilization-6

The Civilization 6 interface apparently doesn't provide any information on why or how borders grow.  I assume its culture with modifiers because that was how it was in Civ 5 and Civ 4, but I have no idea if the formula is the same as Civ 5 or what might affect it.

The only quote I could find [in the manual](http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/289070/manuals/CIV_VI_25TH_ONLINE_MANUAL_ENG.pdf) says:

> The more Culture you generate, the faster your borders will grow

**Does anyone know the formula for border growth in Civ 6?**

A side question:  Are culture producing buildings and districts the best way to have natural border growth (i.e. not purchased)?

Comment: Perhaps user @Ace would know? They [made a mod](http://forums.civfanatics.com/resources/next-city-plot-by-ace.25437) that provides number of turns until border growth and shows a preview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on multiple posts in [this thread](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/civ-vi-how-do-city-borders-expand.602481/), it looks like the border expansion formula has been found in the XML files:

> 1. tiles are obtained with culture produced by the city
> 2. the culture cost of a tile is **10+(6*n)^1.3** (where n is the number of tiles obtained by culture already...not sure if gold bought ones count)